# Apache Zeppelin Big Data Visualization

Tags: apache-zeppelin, bigdata

I tried to use zeppelin to visualize some data from csvs, right now, the data is about 3GBs and 8 million rows approx  and each day, 1GB (2.5 mil rows) added.

Currently, what i tried to do is read all those files locally (based on zeppelin's tutorial given). But the problem is, when i tried to visualize it, there is limitations up to 10000 rows. Indeed, i can increase the limitations, but it still cant covers those millions of rows (timeout)

Am i doing it wrong? Any advice for my case?

Thanks for any responses given.

Answer (score 1):

Visualizing all the data is probably not what you want.

Zeppelin works in browser, thus is you try to display all your data, it will eat all your resources(cpu, memory) and you will get a lot of lags.

Moreover, if you display even a 100K-1M objects it will probably look like a mess or like a big stain, saying nothing.
Wah you can do, is to calculate some **aggregations**, **histograms**, **density of objects** or get **random samples** of the data (there are some built-in methods if you work with spark dataframes and datasets fro example) and visualize these things.
You can calculate some **regression**, **cluster** the data, calculate **moments** and so on, but displaying all the data on a single plot is probably **not what you want**.

Trust me on this, I had once 150+ millions objects infered from social network's user data and tried to get some insight by displaying it. I had to admin, that it was just impossible for me to display all of them on a single picture.

Answer (score 0):

**We visualize the data in order to understand the data. like.**

- How the data is distributed
- Telling trend from the data
- Find pattern in the data

**Certainly we could only put limited amount of point in to a graph. We can**

- Random sampling data
- Sampling data on certain dimension, like time
- Aggregate data by certain dimension

> Have a look at [spark-highchart](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts). It is a library to visualize data with spark to Highcharts. It can be used in Zeppelin.